# Need function to run on selecting an option in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I know this has probably been asked before.

I have this code so far:

```
  <select name="cashfunction" type="text" id="cashfunction" title="Select Function" 

    class="required">
                     <option id="cashfloat">Cash Float</option>
                     <option id="cashvari">Cash Variance</option>
                     <option id="expenditure" value="1">Expenditure</option>
                     <option id="cashbanked" value="2">Cash Banked</option>
    </select>



 <script>
        function bankCategory()
                               {
                               document.getElementById('bankcat').style.visibility='visible';
                               $('.dynamicreq').addClass("required");
                               }
        function expendCategory()
                               {
                               document.getElementById('expend').style.visibility='visible';
                               $('.dynamicreq').addClass("required");
                               }

        $('#cashfunction').on("change", function() {
                                                if($(this).val() === 1)
                                                    {bankCategory();
                                                    }

                                                if($(this).val() === 2)
                                                    {expendCategory();
                                                    }
                                            }
                                 );
    </script>
```

I need the divs by id to remain hidden until selected.
At the moment both divs are hidden but remain hidden when I select from the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason your current code doesn't work is that you are using `===` to compare the string returned from `.val()` with numeric values `1` and `2`. The `===` operator checks that the operands have the same value *and* type, so won't return true. Either use `==` instead, which does some implicit type conversion, or, better, compare strings with strings rather than relying on type conversion:

```
if($(this).val() === "1")
```

If it were my code I would not define separate functions for each value though, I'd try to make my code a bit more generic by having the option elements somehow specify the related divs:

```
<select name="cashfunction" type="text" id="cashfunction" title="Select Function" class="required">
    <option id="cashfloat">Cash Float</option>
    <option id="cashvari">Cash Variance</option>
    <option id="expenditure" data-assoc="bankcat" value="1">Expenditure</option>
    <option id="cashbanked" data-assoc="expend" value="2">Cash Banked</option>
</select>
<div id="bankcat" class="optional">Bank Category div</div>
<div id="expend" class="optional">Expenditure Category div</div>
```

...and then use JS something like this:

```
$('#cashfunction').on("change", function () {
  $("div.optional").hide();
  var associatedDivId = $(this).find("option").filter(":selected").attr("data-assoc");
  if (associatedDivId) {
    $("#" + associatedDivId).show();
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b372b/

Note that in my demo I used `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` because then I was able to just use `.hide()` and `.show()`, but if you want to keep using `visibility` it would be:

```
$("#" + associatedDivId).css("visibility", "visible");
```

You didn't actually include the markup for your divs in the question, but if you give them all a common class it makes it easy to hide them again if the selection is changed. (Your question never specifically says that you want to hide them again, so if not obviously you can just remove the `.hide()` statement.)

If using `data-` attributes seems too complicated you could just put the id of the associated divs in the `value` property, and then the JS would be:

```
  var associatedDivId = $(this).val();
```

Regarding where you've coded `$('.dynamicreq').addClass("required");` - I assume those `.dynamicreq` elements are within the divs that are being hidden or shown, but note that `.addClass()` will add the new class to all of them *including* the hidden ones.

Comment: Thank you turns out it is because I did not put value 1 and 2 in inverted commas